# FILE and *fp translation

Tags: c, python-3.x

I am working on a project using python but I was given example code in C and I just want to know what is the meaning of **FILE** and the * in *fp.
the actual example line of code that was given to me was:

```
    int read_data(FILE *fp, int *id, double *prob_unm, double prob_mut)
```

Comment: Perhaps [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) from the C standard library will shed some light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your line of code, `fp` means "file pointer". In the C standard library, for example when using the `fopen` function to open a file, a **FILE** pointer is returned. **FILE** is a kind of structure that holds information about the file. It is returned as a pointer because a reference to it is needed, as it will get changed by other low-level functions, eg. `fclose`.

In Python, the equivalent is a file object, like the one returned by the `file` or `open` functions.

Answer (score 1):

FILE is a datatype - actually a C structure.  Typically, it's created and returned by a call to "fopen()".

The * denotes that read_data expects a pointer to a FILE structure, as opposed to the whole data structure itself. That's fine, since we mostly pass pointers to structures around anyway.

So, a sample call might be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    int id = 123;
    double prob_unm = 0.25;
    double prob_mut = 0.5;

    fp = fopen ("file.txt", "r");
    int n = read_data(fp, &id, &prob_unm, &prob_mut)
    fclose(fp);

    printf("%d %d %lf %lf", n, id, prob_unm, prob_mut);
 }
```

Notice the * s on the int and double arguments.  Even though I've set them to values like 0.25, etc in the code above, the fact that they're '*'d typically means that the method intends to write to them - so the 'printf' above will probably show different values from what I've assigned them.

Oh, and the '&' that I put in the function call is effectively the 'opposite' of the '*' - it means, given a variable, return a pointer to that variable.  It's how Passing-By-Reference is performed in C.

Comment: Oops - just nioticed that you have a '*' on prob_unm, but NOT on prob_mut.  Is that intentional?  If so, remove the '&' from the call to read_data for prob_mut.